# Hive table for an external Snappy avro data shows compression is false

Tags: hive, avro

Imported single table using sqoop

```
...
--as-avrodatafile
--compression-codec ...SnappyCodec
...
```

Viewing in Hue file browser confirms that it is compressed by displaying a message `Output rendered from compressed avro file.`

Created external table in Hive as

```
create external table customers_avro
stored as avro
location '.../path/'
tblproperties('avro.schema.file'='/path/to/customers.avsc')
```

However, when querying with `describe extended tblname` shows `compressed:false`

```
...
inputFormat:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat, outputFormat:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat, compressed:false, numBuckets:-1, serdeInfo:SerDeInfo(name:null, serializationLib:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe, parameters:{serialization.format=1})...
```

Is there any other property that needs to be set with `tblproperties`?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest verify if your data is properly compressed. You can use this.

[Compression codec detection in Hadoop from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26934551/compression-codec-detection-in-hadoop-from-the-command-line),

Also, should be useful know your hive and sqoop versions, try to import from sqoop like this

```
--compression-codec snappy
```