# How to detect type of compression (if no header is provided)

Tags: binary, reverse-engineering, compression

I have a blob of binary data (network capture) that is parsed by a binary on my machine. I am assuming that because the binary expects a type of data, no header information indicating the type of compression is necessary as that would be wasted bandwidth. How then, if given an arbitrary amount of binary data, can I determine the method of compression? Also how do I go about decompressing?

PEiD plugin "Kanal" tells me the binary has "BZIP2 [long]" and "ZLIB deflate [long]" features in it, but what program can I use to say "treat this arbitrary data like it's bzip2, even though there is no header/magic number, and see what the decompression result is" and where "bzip2" can be replaced with 
any compression method? Is this possible?

edit: this is similar to: [How to detect type of compression used on the file? (if no file extension is specified)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19120676/how-to-detect-type-of-compression-used-on-the-file-if-no-file-extension-is-spe) only this time, no header info is specified.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just start decompressing.  zlib will detect very quickly if it is not deflate data being fed to it.  I don't know how quickly libbzip2 will figure that out, but if you have only those two choices then just try zlib first.