# django check if the uploaded file is a zip file

Tags: python, django, zip

I have a handler for a POST method in Django which receives an uploaded file. What I would like to do is verify that the file is a valid zip file before proceeding.

So, I have:

```
@login_required(login_url="login/")
def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['upload_file']:
        uploaded_file = request.FILES['upload_file']
        print type(uploaded_file)

    return render(request, 'upload.html', {'context': RequestContext(request)})
```

Now at this point `uploaded_file` is of type `<class 'django.core.files.uploadedfile.InMemoryUploadedFile'>`. My question is what would be the best way to verify that this is a valid archive? Do I need to save it to the disk and then use the `zipfile` module or is there some way to do it without writing to the disk?

Note: I am not using the Django model with a FileField and the corresponding Form for various unrelated reasons.

Comment: What about checking the file extension?

Comment: Cannot be relied upon unfortunately for my application...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you should use `zipfile` module.

`zipfile.is_zipfile(filename)`

Returns True if filename is a valid ZIP file based on its magic number, otherwise returns False. filename may be a file or file-like object too.
(Changed in version 3.1: Support for file and file-like objects.)

**Another option:**(not likely but your choice)

[How to detect type of compression used on the file? (if no file extension is specified)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19120676/how-to-detect-type-of-compression-used-on-the-file-if-no-file-extension-is-spe)

You can find the header formats in the descriptions:

Zip (.zip) format description, starts with 0x50, 0x4b, 0x03, 0x04 (unless empty — then the last two are 0x05, 0x06 or 0x06, 0x06)

Comment: yeah, the thing is that the file will have to be stored to be able to use with `zipfile`. I guess there is no other really good way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Save the filename of the pbject

```
Name = request.FILES['filename'].name
```

Then check if is a zip file

```
If Name.endswith('.zip'):
     print(True)
```

Comment: It has the same issue as I mentioned before of having to store the file. I guess there is no really good and robust way to check an in-memory file.