# How to determine which algorithm of compression was used on a file?

Tags: linux, algorithm, compression

I'm doing a little of ctf stuff and my job is to find out which unpopular algorithm of compression was used to compress the file with the format .sbx. The "file" command on the file returns name: data , I've also tried TriDNet on this file, tar,bzip2,zip . The format of the file is unknown and I was given a password to decompress the file so if someone could give me a clue I would really appreciate. When I run hd on the file the head is 0;

Comment: Might be: [How to detect type of compression used on the file? (if no file extension is specified)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19127748/7501501), if this is not what you are looking for please comment.

Comment: I think you should add the `linux tag`, there are many linux tools that can be useful here.

Comment: @Yonlif I used that already didn't work :/

Comment: When I need to understand a file, binary image or compression I usually use [binwalk](https://tools.kali.org/forensics/binwalk).

Comment: Can you share this file or a link to it? Maybe tell us it's source? Is it possible that it was corrupted in some way? If we are talking about ctf's maybe you need to be creative about it.