# Find compression algorithm of NSData

Tags: swift, cocoa, compression, nsdata

When using `decompressed(using:)` method of `NSData` I have to provide a `NSData.CompressionAlgorithm` to uncompress the data.
Is there a way to detect the compression method of a `NSData` object so I don't have to know which method was used for compressing?

Comment: Why would you need to detect if you already know which one you have used?

Comment: I don't know which Algorithm is used in my NSData object. As I am handling with multiple Algorithms I have to check for each every time I want to access these data

Comment: It seems that some of the format might have a "start of file" proper to them, with no guarantee though that the file is fully compliant. A little like a JPEG starts with `FFD8FF`... I'm not sure at all, I'm just wondering if it could be a search start...

Comment: You are the one who compressed the data. Just keep that info for later usage.

Comment: I did not compress the data (I never wrote this) I am importing NSData from files where I do not know if or which algorithm was used!

Comment: @MikeNathas ..so can you make sense of the (decomp.) data and trial various compression methods to see which returns sensible, uncompressed data?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect type of compression used on the file? (if no file extension is specified)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19120676/how-to-detect-type-of-compression-used-on-the-file-if-no-file-extension-is-spe)

Comment: In general a good idea, but as always Apple is cooks their own soup and they don't use the official implementation but uses their own custom ones. I'll export a bit data, maybe there is a pattern but I think the only solution will be just try out every algorithm until valid data is there.